# Certificate request to X.509

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

Might be a stupid question, but is there any way to create (self-signed) X.509 certificate based on a CSR sent to me? I need to do it programmatically.
Using Java 1.6 and Bouncy-castle ver 1.51.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer to your question is 'yes', and *how* to do it will be found in the documentation, which you should have consulted before asking.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to find some info regarding this in documentation, but couldn't. That's why I asked here.
Maybe you have some tips where to look?

Answer (score 2):

No, obviously you cannot as you would not posses the private key if the CSR was **sent to you**, which is required to sign the final certificate data (the data "to be signed" or TBS).

You can of course copy the data within the CSR that would otherwise be in the self-signed certificate, replace the public key and then sign with your own private key. This would of course require programming, and that's great because you posted this on a programming Q/A site.

Comment: Thank you! Seems I need to find some way to wrap csr info into the certificate.

Comment: Parse PKCS#10, create new PKCS#10. Or binary replace the modulus (the public exponent is probably `0x010001` (65537) anyway and the modulus is statically sized. Of course the key size needs to be the same in that case.